# OCI run time error Flask app and Docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker

Every time I run docker-compose up I get this ERROR related to the pathing of uwsgi

Recreating flask_app ...
nginx is up-to-date
Recreating flask_app ... error

ERROR: for flask_app  Cannot start service flask: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "uwsgi": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for flask  Cannot start service flask: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "uwsgi": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Docker file

```
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch
WORKDIR /Back-end 
ADD . /Back-end
    
## Install the  dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 

## run the command to start uWSGI

CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

app.ini file

```
 [uwsgi]
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
callable = app
socket = :8080
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please share your Dockerfile and scripts you copy into the container during image creation?

Comment: ya I apologize this was a bad stack over post, I have added what the code looks like

Answer (score 3):

You did not install `uwsgi` in your image. I can reproduce your exact error message with this docker invocation:

```
$ docker run python:stretch uwsgi
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"uwsgi\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

When I start a `python:stretch` container in interactive mode and install `uwsgi` via `pip` I can execute the command successfully:

```
$ pip install uwsgi
....
$ uwsgi --version
2.0.19.1
```

Therefore you should be able to fix your problem by adding `uwsgi` to your requirements.txt to install it while building your image.